# Silence logger for just one controller in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

We have one controller which produces too much logs (which we don't care about). We want to silence these logs.

We found several solution, but all of them end up having one of two issues:

- We use in development a default ActiveRecord logger, while in production SysLog (https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/syslog/rdoc/Syslog/Logger.html)

It looks like a lot of solutions (which we found) are targeting specifically ActiveRecord logger (vs any logger).

- It looks like if we do anything with ActiveRecord::Base.logger then it end up being applied to ALL controllers (vs just this one).

Comment: Is the controller under your control?

Comment: @max Yes. It's our application controller.

Comment: Can't you just fix the problem directly?

Comment: @max Not really. As an example, ActiveRecord spits out logs for SQL which it executes (which is probably one of the noisies thing). So I can't just comment out a line in controller or do something like that to get rid of logs.

Comment: where you able to resolve this?

Comment: @renen sorry don't remember the details. it ended up being something quite hacky.